# Best way to read/parse XML url in python3

Tags: python, json, xml, parsing

I read a lot of different answers similar questions, but no one seems providing a *simple* solution.

Supposing to have a remote url like this https://www.emidius.eu/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=quakeml:eu.ahead/event/13270512_0000_000&format=xml the final aim is to get an usable python object (e.g. a dictionary or a json like object).

I did find different methods if the xml is save as a local file:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

file = '/home/user/query.xml'
tree = ET.parse(file)
root = tree.getroot()

for c in root:
    print(c.tag)
    for i in c:
        print(i.tag)
```

I did not find a method (with native python modules) to bump a url string and get an object.

Comment: What's wrong about downloading then parsing?

Comment: @Joe because for the workflow I'm facing, I need to directly use an url

Answer (score 0):

OK I think the best solution is this one:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import urllib.request

opener = urllib.request.build_opener()
url = 'https://www.emidius.eu/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=quakeml:eu.ahead/event/13270512_0000_000&includeallorigins=true&includeallmagnitudes=true&format=xml'

tree = ET.parse(opener.open(url))
```

Answer (score 0):

This works, but you don't need `build_opener()` for that. 
You can build a custom opener for some specific case or protocol, but you use normal https. So you can just use

```
import urllib.request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = 'https://www.emidius.eu/fdsnws/event/1/query?eventid=quakeml:eu.ahead/event/13270512_0000_000&includeallorigins=true&includeallmagnitudes=true&format=xml'

with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as response:
   html = ET.fromstring(response.read().decode())
```

Comment: Actually with that I'm getting an error: `File name too long` and the `html` is not created. You will need to remove `read()` from `response`

Comment: Ah, ok. You need to parse from a string, not from `open`. Fixed. Also the bytes has to be decoded.